# Is it possible to finish the Bank Heist without the wire cutters

Tags: thief

I decided to do the Bank Heist mission while still in Chapter 1, so the wire cutters are not available yet. In the vault there is a puzzle to access the final loot. I think I have figured out how to do it but it seems that I need the wire cutters to

> disable the dart trap pressure plates

to be able to do it fast enough.

Is it possible to beat it without the wire cutters or did they really do something as silly as letting me attempt the mission before I had all the tools I needed to complete  the job?

Comment: As a side note, check the side of the necklace box for a button that disables the gas.

Comment: Didn't notice that. You can also just run straight up to the vault door, if you are quick enough you will get out before you take any damage from the gas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can.

There is some loot you can't get to without taking damage if you don't have the wire cutters but you can reach the level goal without them.

After some time away from the game I saw things from a different perspective and figured out how to get to the goal a different way.

If you are stuck and can't figure it out:

> You flip one of the switches, climb up the wall that the switch is on, walk over the cage careful to avoid the trap pressure plates up top and then drop down next to the other switch and flip it, avoiding the pressure plates that reset the switches. If you are in focus mode, the trap plates glow red and the ones that reset the switches glow blue. You need to be relatively quick but not nearly as perfect as the route under the stairs that I had previously been trying.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got to the level goal without using the wire cutters?

Comment: I'll add it in in a spoiler tag since it goes a little out of the scope of this question.

Comment: It feels like inside the scope to me. Yes "here is howto do it" sounds like a better answer then "Yes, I did it, so it's possible"

Comment: My question wasn't how you solve it, I was asking if it was solvable. I'm glad I figured it out before someone spoiled it for me, if at all possible I like solving the puzzles myself.

Comment: I like your current answer +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but instead of cutting the wires you climb the wall next to the levers and walk across and drop down in front of the 2nd lever though watch out if your not careful when you get the necklace the room begins to fill with gas.

Comment: You might want to put the solution part in a spoiler tag, the question was **IF** not _HOW_. I very intentionally phrased the question like that to avoid spoilers for myself and others who like to solve the puzzles themselves.